# Characteristic Polynomial via Induction

Tags: linear-algebra

I sort of understand where the equation of the Char Poly comes from, but i'm having problems setting up the induction.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you having problems with, the formula for determinant, induction,..

Comment: Setting up the Induction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simplifies notation slightly to let $\beta_k = \alpha_{n-k}$.

Let $A_n = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -\beta_n \\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -\beta_{n-1}  \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & -\beta_{n-2} \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \vdots & 1 & -\beta_1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $xI-A_n = \begin{bmatrix} x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \beta_n \\
-1 & x & \cdots & 0 & \beta_{n-1}  \\
0 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & \beta_{n-2} \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \vdots & -1 & x+\beta_1
\end{bmatrix}$.

and let $p_n(x) = \det(xI -A_n)$.

Suppose $p_{n-1}$ is known. Then using the definition of the determinant and noting that the only non-zero elements on the top row of $xI-A_n$ are $x$ and $\beta_n$, we see that
$p_n(x)=\det(xI -A_n) = x \det(xI -A_{n-1}) +(-1)^{n-1} (-1)^{n-1} \beta_n = x p_{n-1}(x)+\beta_n$. Since
$p_1(x) = x+\beta_1$, we have the desired result.